# Excel: How to count time between dates that match on one criteria

Tags: excel, date, time, count, between

I need to find out the time it takes to move a record from one status to another in business days. (in my example the time between Edit Dates for one Case Number)
In my case it is the status from "Working" to "Waiting On" and vice versa.

The result should be e.g.:

- Working: 3.1 business days
- Waiting On: 2.4 business days

I was trying various combination around this excel function:

```
=IF(MATCH([@[Case Number]],[Case Number],0),NETWORKDAYS([@[Edit Date]],OFFSET([@[Edit Date]], -1,0)),0)
```

This is the basic dataset I query:

```
||Date/Time Opened|Edit Date|NEW Case Close Date|Field / Event|Old Value|New Value|Waiting On|Case Number||
|28.03.2017 12:58|29.03.2017 20:52|11.12.2017 04:54|Status|Working|Waiting On|Customer|1203261|
|28.03.2017 12:58|11.12.2017 04:54|11.12.2017 04:54|Status|Waiting On|Working|Customer|1203261|
|28.03.2017 16:56|29.03.2017 20:14|11.12.2017 04:55|Status|Working|Waiting On|Customer|1203350|
|28.03.2017 16:56|11.12.2017 04:55|11.12.2017 04:55|Status|Waiting On|Working|Customer|1203350|
|05.04.2017 16:41|06.04.2017 16:58|30.10.2017 14:00|Status|Working|Waiting On|Customer|1209806|
|05.04.2017 16:41|10.04.2017 14:51|30.10.2017 14:00|Status|Waiting On|Working|Customer|1209806|
|05.04.2017 16:41|12.04.2017 17:08|30.10.2017 14:00|Status|Working|Waiting On|Customer|1209806|
|05.04.2017 16:41|14.04.2017 08:40|30.10.2017 14:00|Status|Waiting On|Working|Customer|1209806|
|05.04.2017 16:41|21.04.2017 14:58|30.10.2017 14:00|Status|Working|Waiting On|Customer|1209806|
```

Comment: Can you tell me how your calculation would come to 3.1 and 2.4? And what line on your sample data?

Comment: that was just a random number an no real calculation - sry.
it should basically sum up the lines where case number and old value match.
hope that makes more sense

Comment: Not really, simply edit your question with some clear calculation/expected outcome with the lines of data provided